# python sql magic issue with oracle 12.1.0.2.0

Tags: python, ipython

I follow the instruction to install sql magic.

https://github.com/catherinedevlin/ipython-sql

I got the following errors

```
/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/config.py:13: ShimWarning: The `IPython.config` package has been deprecated since IPython 4.0. You should import from traitlets.config instead.
  "You should import from traitlets.config instead.", ShimWarning)
/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/utils/traitlets.py:5: UserWarning: IPython.utils.traitlets has moved to a top-level traitlets package.
  warn("IPython.utils.traitlets has moved to a top-level traitlets package.")
```

It looks like its just warning so I move forward to  try to connect to the Oracle DB The version is 12.1.0.2.0

but still error out...

The end of the error stack:

```
/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/oracle/cx_oracle.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    707 
    708         if hasattr(self.dbapi, 'version'):
--> 709             self.cx_oracle_ver = tuple([int(x) for x in
    710                                         self.dbapi.version.split('.')])
    711         else:

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0b2'
```

Comment: That's a warning. Meaning sql magic probably did actually install. Can you please check?

Comment: Its intall but now I got this error: see edit above

Answer (score 0):

I cannot get sql magic to work but I find an easier solution.

Just do this

```
import pandas as pd
print(con.version)
query = """select * from all_tab_columns"""
df_ora = pd.read_sql(query, con=con)
```